# Working with dates in Excel older than 1900

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Are there any workarounds for working with time and date data prior to January 1, 1900? Excel seems to just assign my values dates in 1900 rather than keeping them intact.

Comment: Can you give us some more information on how you're manipulating data?  If the data is just being entered, 4-digit year seems to work for me.  Are you using it in formulas or dependencies?

Comment: @BrianDaniels Are you using a newer version of Excel and/or dates since 1900?  Excel dates are an (unsigned) offset from 1/1/1900.  (Hint: try sorting them...)

Comment: I'm working with dates from 0 C.E. through about 1700 C.E. Using `yyyy` also forces the dates to 1900.

Comment: Using 4-digit year in Excel 2007

Comment: If you enter 1/1/1899, 1/1/1900, 1/1/1901 in Excel and then sort "oldest to newest", it puts the 1899 date last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas from [exceluser.com](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/earlydates.htm):

- Enter them **as text**, in YYYY-MM-DD format.  This should allow sorting to work as expected.
- Create or install a macro that converts dates before 1900 to a negative serial.  (The site links one.)