# Excel: How to type in date and time, like "1/23/1945 16:20:14" (not Ctrl + ;)

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, date

I need to enter various time points including y,m,d,h, m, s. Examples:

```
"1/23/1945 16:20:14"
"1/23/1967 08:00"
```

Excel only recognizes above as text, not saved as serial number. Any format for entry is fine by me. 
Using TIMEVALUE() doesn't always recognize the input
Dates are historical so not possible to use Ctrl+;.
Thanks.

Comment: do they actually have the `""` around them?  What is you local settings?  when I add the values without the quotes excel recognizes it as a date/time not a string.

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps to type in date & time, and have it properly formatted by Microsoft Excel:

- Select the cell where you want to paste the date
- Tap <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit the cell inline
- Copy/paste the following: *(notice the lack of quotation marks)*

  > ```
  > 1/23/1945 16:20:14
  > ```
- Or copy/paste this one:

  > ```
  > 1/23/1967 08:00
  > ```

Verified in Microsoft Office 2013:

[image]

Comment: these turn to serial numbers when change format from short date to serial number
7/20/1969
5/26/1926
5/14/2018
1/23/1945
1/23/1945
5/26/2026
These do not change to serial number when change format:
7/4/1776 12:00
3/4/1861 16:30
03/04/1861 16:30
I'm wondering if it has to do with pre- post- 1900.

Comment: Following type-in will show serial number when format to number:
1/1/1900 01:02
This typed in will not convert to serial number:
12/31/1899 01:02

Comment: Ah, yes. Pre-1900 dates are a problem in MS-Excel. Related: https://superuser.com/questions/562520/working-with-dates-in-excel-older-than-1900